# Inject form factory into a service

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms

I'm trying to create a manager to handle basic requests of a controller (list, new, edit, delete). I need to inject the form factory within the constructor of this service. By what name should I call?

I need something like this:

```
lp_ExpedienteManager:
    class: AppBundle\Services\ExpedienteManager\ExpedienteManager
    arguments:    [ "@doctrine.orm.entity_manager", "@security.token_storage", "@form_factory" ]
```

Thanks for your time!

Comment: Sorry, it's a bit hard to tell what exactly you need here. Do you have the manager class already?

Comment: may not ask nicely, english is not my primary language. For example to inject EntityManager use "@ doctrine.orm.entity_manager". What would be the string for injecting the form factory? i need form factory to do "$this->createForm(ExpedienteType::class, $expediente)" inside the service.

Comment: bin/console debug:container | grep form

Comment: It's just what I needed! Thanks Cerad!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

For future references, since Symfony 3.3 this service is available as Symfony\Component\Form\FormFactoryInterface. So you can inject in your services like

```
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormFactoryInterface;

class AccountBridge
{
    private $formFactory;
    public function __construct(FormFactoryInterface $formFactory)
    {
        $this->formFactory = $formFactory;
    }

    public function accountCreateAction(Account $account)
    {
        $form = $this->formFactory->create(AccountType::class, $account);
    }
}
```